# pam_exec not working? cannot allocate 2 bytes?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ubuntu-12.04, pam

I am trying to run a script during the login process using PAM and libpam_exec;

I have added this line to the desired file under /etc/pam.d/:

```
auth required pam_exec.so debug log=/var/log/debug /usr/local/bin/test.sh
```

and just to test if it was working, the script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
## do nothing, except return success (allow login..)
exit 0;
```

however, the client is rejected with "critical error", and the debug log reports this strange error:

```
bash: xmalloc: ../bash/locale.c:73: cannot allocate 2 bytes (0 bytes allocated)
```

I have looked everywhere, and have not been able to turn up anything useful on this particular issue.. the debug log is incredibly vague, and I am simply not sure where to go from here?

I thought about (as a last resort) digging up the source code to bash to see what’s on line 73 of locale.c.. or simply using another module... but I have multiple plans for pam_exec, and I don't particularly like the implementation of (for example) pam_script.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

note: running Ubuntu 12.04 lts